# Offline Location Update is not working in iOS 14 and above

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

I am working on the Location update in my application
When the app is with internet connection location update (didUpdateLocation) is called. But when the app goes offline, Location update delegate is not called in iOS 14 . I am not getting the latitude and longitude.
Any idea why this is happening or is this the process of location manager?

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
    if([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]){
      [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }else{
      [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    lattitude =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude] ;
    longitude =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.longitude];
    
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
  
}
```

Comment: Please share some code. Core Location frameworks delegate method didUpdateLocation called when user's device is reachable to internet or not.

Comment: updated the code

Comment: Facing the same issue. Any help is appreciated.